# AzDO in Chrome being forced to Save with No Edit

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

When navigating AzDo in Chrome I receive the pop up

"Are you sure you want to leave this page?
You have unsaved changes
You can save your changes, discard your changes, cancel to continue editing"

I am only viewing and never enter an Edit state.  This happens with Work Items and Queries.  Have tried to delete viewing cache and TFS cache but I cant seem to shake this edit.

Comment: Have you tried the same operation in other browser such as IE or Edge and could the problem be reproduced in any of those? Press Ctrl+Shift+N in Chrome will open you a private mode tab, have you tested in it? Can you describe the operation specifically which could reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'll describe the scenario where I've seen this occur:

Open the Queries;  Select to create a new Query.  You filter for a list of work items.  You find the work item you want to view in the list and you open it.  If you watch the URL, you'll notice you haven't really navigated anywhere new.  You have only opened the work item in context of the query.  You are currently sitting on the work item view and have not edited anything.  Now you try to navigate away to a different URL.  You get prompted because you are still on the context of the query and you have not saved the query.  The unsaved changes are likely for the query and not the work item.